# How to define config file variables?

Tags: configuration, erlang, erlang-otp

I have a configuration file with:

```
{path, "/mnt/test/"}.
{name, "Joe"}.
```

The path and the name could be changed by a user. As I know, there is a way to save those variables in a module by usage of  `file:consult/1` in

```
-define(VARIABLE, <parsing of the config file>).
```

Are there any better ways to read a config file when the module begins to work without making a parsing function in -define? (As I know, according to Erlang developers, it's not the best way to make a complicated functions in -define)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to store config only when you start the application - you may use application config file which is defined in 'rebar.config'

```
{profiles, [
  {local,
    [{relx, [
      {dev_mode,      false},
      {include_erts,  true},
      {include_src,   false},
      {vm_args,       "config/local/vm.args"}]
      {sys_config,    "config/local/yourapplication.config"}]
     }]
  }
]}.
```

more info about this here: [rebar3 configuration](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/configuration)

next step to create `yourapplication.config` - store it in your application folder `/app/config/local/yourapplication.config`

this configuration should have structure like this example

```
[
    {
        yourapplicationname, [
            {path, "/mnt/test/"},
            {name, "Joe"}
        ]
    }
].
```

so when your application is started
you can get the whole config data with

```
{ok, "/mnt/test/"} = application:get_env(yourapplicationname, path)
{ok, "Joe"} = application:get_env(yourapplicationname, name)
```

and now you may -define this variables like:

```
-define(VARIABLE,
    case application:get_env(yourapplicationname, path) of
        {ok, Data} -> Data
        _   -> undefined
    end
).
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! Another question is how to make these two variables global for the module? As I understand, the only way is to declare the variables by application:get_env in "-define", am I right? P.S. without ets/dets/mnesia usage

Comment: @NickSaw updated the answer (added -define variable)

Comment: Thank you for reply, I understand